# Diferença entre null, empty, 0 e false apanhando o registro no banco de dados

Tags: php

Eu acabei de ver um artigo mostrando como mudar o `null` para false e 0 também, porém não estou sabendo fazer isso quando uma informação está no meu banco de dados e ele é do tipo 0 e 1 e queria por sim ou não na sua atribuição.

```
 <label><h3 class="h3"><?php echo $list['Nome_da_coluna']; ?></h3>  </label>
```

está me retornado o select funcionando normal porém não consigo mudar ele para sim ou não no PHP ele só me mostra 0 e 1, estou precisando de um modo para executar pois eu não estou sabendo implementar.

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow. Primeiramente aqui é uma comunidade de perguntas e respostas compostas por várias pessoas. Recomendo que comece fazendo um [tour] para entender melhor os objetivos da comunidade ;)

Comment: Tentei melhorar a pergunta mas ainda não entendi o que você quer. Seria bom [edit] a pergunta e deixar mais claro. Procure caprichar no texto para que as pessoas possam entender o que você deseja e possam lhe ajudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma maneira diferente da já citada é fazer isso diretamente no banco:

```
$sql = 'SELECT nome, idade, IF(flag_ativo = 0, "Não", "Sim") AS esta_ativo FROM tabelaExemplo';
```

Neste exemplo eu pego os campos nome, idade e faço um IF no campo flag_ativo setando ele como Sim ou Não. No php você poderia intão fazer novamente assim:

```
<label><h3 class="h3"><?php echo $list['esta_ativo']; ?></h3></label>
```

O ganho de performance é praticamente irrelevante, portanto recomendo tambem o método sugerido pelo @KaduAmaral

Link para a função [IF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if).

Para campos Nulos você pode experimentar o [IFNULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull).

Comment: Como a base de dados sabe a qual campo o if está se referindo?

Comment: Você deve destacar o campo no IF. No meu exemplo coloquei nomes poucos significativos. Vou editar e colocar nomes mais claros;

Comment: Vale ainda usar os dois, em casos necessários: `IF(IFNULL(flag_ativo,0) = 0, "Não", "Sim")`

Comment: Kaminary obrigado por ter apanhado o meu caso, estarei testando esse método fico bastante grato.

Comment: Certo @AngeloAugusto, apenas tome cuidado, pois fazendo isso no banco o trafego de rede ira aumentar, uma vez que você está transferindo 3 caracteres ao invés de 1 numero para cada registro. Caso o banco seja localhost a diferença é desprezivel.

Comment: Opá Obrigado pelo alerta vou tomar esse cuidado sim Muito Obrigado =]

Answer (score 2):

Então, é só você fazer um `IF`, ou melhor ainda, uma **[condição ternária](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/operador-ternario/).**

```
<?php $list['Nome_da_coluna'] = ($list['Nome_da_coluna'] == '1' ? 'Sim' : 'Não'); ?>

<label><h3 class="h3"><?php echo $list['Nome_da_coluna']; ?></h3></label>
```

Que significa, `se $list['Nome_da_coluna] é igual a '1' imprima 'Sim' senão imprima 'Não'`.

Procure sempre pesquisar e estudar antes de fazer uma pergunta. Estamos aqui pra ajudar, mas esse tipo de resposta você encontra aos montes pela internet.

Comment: Opá muito obrigado por olhar o emu caso meu querido porem já fiz exatamente assim na verdade foi a primeira técnica que ue usei e não obtive sucesso. Mesmo assim fico bastante grato meu caro =]